# Changed bool value but it changes back during next loop of while statement

Tags: c++, boolean

I am trying to create a BFS tree using c++ code. I'm fairly certain that my code works, but every time I try to change the boolean value of 'explored' to true(in the last if statement of the code) to mark a node as visited, it changes back to false in the next loop of the function. I've posted my BFS function below so if anyone could explain to me exactly why the value keeps changing back to false it would be very helpful since I'm not quite sure whats going wrong.

```
  void BFS(int s,int n, vector<vector<int> > node_list) {
    queue<int> Q;


    bool *explored = new bool[n+1];//  it Keeps track of explored vertices

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)// Initialization of  all vertices as unexplored
    explored[i] = false;
    Q.push(s);// Pushing of  initial vertex to the queue
    explored[s] = true; // marking it as explored
    cout << "Breadth first Search starting from vertex ";
    cout << s << " : " << endl;

    while (!Q.empty()) {
        int v = Q.front();
        Q.pop();
        cout << v << " ";
        cout << explored[1]<<explored[2]<<explored[3]<<explored[4]<<endl;
        vector<int> current_list = node_list[v-1];

        for (int i = 0;i<current_list.size();i++){
            for (int w = 1; w <= n; ++w){
                if ((w == current_list[i]) && (explored[w] != true)) {
                    cout << "in if: "<< w<<", "<<explored[w]<< endl;
                    Q.push(w);
                    explored[w] = true;
                }
            } 
        }
    cout << endl;
    delete [] explored;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have 3 nested loops. Could you point out which of these is the "next loop"? Also, ideally, show a minimal complete example with output that actually demonstrates the problem. I can't compile that one function to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Little off topic, but you only read from `node_list` but you take it by value (so it copies a vector of vectors... ouch).

Comment: Another issue is in general, mixing in 1-based array processing with 0-based processing is a recipe for some off-by-1 error to occur at some point.  In C++, arrays / buffers start at 0, not 1.  If I had a dollar for every time someone tries to fake 1-based processing, and then have an off-by-one bug, I would be a rich man.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with proper formatting:

```
void BFS(int s,int n, vector<vector<int> > node_list) {
    queue<int> Q;

    bool *explored = new bool[n+1]; // it Keeps track of explored vertices

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) // Initialization of  all vertices as unexplored
        explored[i] = false;

    Q.push(s); // Pushing of  initial vertex to the queue
    explored[s] = true; // marking it as explored
    cout << "Breadth first Search starting from vertex ";
    cout << s << " : " << endl;

    while (!Q.empty()) {
        int v = Q.front();
        Q.pop();
        cout << v << " ";
        cout << explored[1]<<explored[2]<<explored[3]<<explored[4]<<endl;
        vector<int> current_list = node_list[v-1];

        for (int i = 0;i<current_list.size();i++){
            for (int w = 1; w <= n; ++w){
                if ((w == current_list[i]) && (explored[w] != true)) {
                    cout << "in if: "<< w<<", "<<explored[w]<< endl;
                    Q.push(w);
                    explored[w] = true;
                }
            } 
        }
        cout << endl;
        delete [] explored;
    }
}
```

it's easy to see that you delete the dynamically allocated `explored` each iteration.